# not getting forbidden attribute error.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `rails4 and ruby2.0.0`

When I do

```
 def create
    @post  = Post.create(params[:post])
    redirect_to posts_path
 end
```

then I get `forbidden attribute error`, which is ok - I know this behaviour means I have to permit params like `params.require(:post).permit(:title,:content)`

But when I do this

```
def create
    @post  = Post.create(:title=>params[:post][:title], :content=>params[:post][:content])
    redirect_to posts_path
end
```

it doesn't asks for permitting params, i.e., I didn't get any forbidden attribute error, it saves the post record in database.

Can anyone please explain me this strange behaviour, why 2nd one does not require params to permit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing here is that **params** is not just a hash, it is an instance of ActionController::Parameters class, which mostly behaves like a hash, but also responds to #permitted? method, #require and so on. Thus, when you call

```
Post.create(params[:post])
```

Rails internally calls #permitted? method on params[:post], which returns false, and you get forbidden attribute error. 
But when you manually extract attributes from params

```
 :title=>params[:post][:title], :content=>params[:post][:content]
```

You get simple Hash object, which does not implement any such behavior, and the post is successfully saved.

[More in Rails documentation on ActionController::Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html)