# Failing to update single attribute in Rails, error with params[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord

Trying to update user attributes to include Songkick ID.

In the view, I have the following code for my form helper:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.text_field :songkickID %>

  <%= f.submit "Songkick ID", :type => :image, :src => image_path("songkicklogo.png"), id: "skLogo" %>
<% end %>
```

In the page source code, I see this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/1" class="edit_user" id="edit_user_1" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="asdal;skalskd;laskd;asdj=" />
</div>

  <input id="user_songkickID" name="user[songkickID]" type="text" />

  <input id="skLogo" name="commit" src="/assets/songkicklogo.png" type="image" value="Songkick ID" />
```

So it looks to me like it should be updating the user attribute via the text field. It isn't, however, when I check the user in the Rails console, the songkickid is nil.

The update method in the User controller is as follows:

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attribute(:songkickID, params[:songkickID])

  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
end
end
```

If I change params[:songkickID] manually to a valid Songkick ID, it works, so I'm guessing the fault is with that params[:songkickID]? Or with the text field? Or both?

Comment: you should do params[:user][:songkickID], your params is nested inside user , as your resource is user..

Comment: and the way u are updating is also wrong u should do update_attributes(songkickID: params[:user][:songkickID]), and dont forget to permit params if u are using rails4

Comment: Thanks for that, updated link like in your 2nd comment and it worked, I'll set that as the answer! I didn't need to change any permissions, does that mean I should check to see if my parameters are strong?

Comment: i think the way u map your params as in my 2nd comment, u don't need to permit it...i dont know why but u dont need to do that, i had already asked a question about that see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928335/not-getting-forbidden-attribute-error but did'nt find answers yet

Comment: Fair enough, how do I set your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your params is nested inside "user" so you should do

```
@user.update_attributes(songkickID: params[:user][:songkickID])
```